# SQL Query within view

Tags: c#, html, sql

I'm trying to display the results of a query on the IMPORT_TRACKER table in my cshtml. I have the following...

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.IMPORT_TRACKER>
@using System.Data.SqlClient;
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Import Selection";

string connString42 = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
using (SqlConnection _theconny42 = new SqlConnection(connString42))
{
    foreach (var row in _theconny42.Query("SELECT MAX(IMPORT_DATE) FROM IMPORT_TRACKER;"))
    {
@row.IMPORT_DATE;
    }
    }
}
```

I'm unsure on the syntax to perform the query. It currently gives an error " 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' does not contain a definition for 'Query' "

I've added the query to the ImportController.cs

```
public ActionResult ImportSelection()
    {
        {
        var result = "SELECT MAX(IMPORT_DATE) FROM IMPORT_TRACKER;"; 
        return View(result);
        }
    }
```

And in ImportSelection.cshtml

```
       @foreach (var item in Model)
       {
           <div>@item</div>
       }
```

I'm getting an error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BillingApp.Models.IMPORT_TRACKER]'."

```
@model IEnumerable<BillingApp.Models.IMPORT_TRACKER>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Import Selection";

}
```

I'm not sure what to assign to result

```
   public ActionResult ImportSelection()
    {
        {
            string connString42 = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
            using (SqlConnection _theconny42 = new SqlConnection(connString42))
            {
                _theconny42.Open();
                string lastimport = "SELECT MAX(IMPORT_DATE) FROM IMPORT_TRACKER;";
                SqlCommand Commander42 = new SqlCommand(lastimport, _theconny42);
                var result = Commander42.ExecuteNonQuery();
                return View(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I closer...?

```
   public ActionResult ImportSelection()
    {
        {
                var result = db.IMPORT_TRACKER("SELECT MAX(IMPORT_DATE) FROM IMPORT_TRACKER;");
                return View(result);
        }
    }
```

I tried this...

```
  public ActionResult ImportSelection()
    {
        {
                string db = "Data Source=SWDB10DSQL;Initial Catalog=BillingUI;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";
                string query = "SELECT MAX(IMPORT_DATE) FROM IMPORT_TRACKER;";
                var result = db.IMPORT_TRACKER(query);
                return View(result);
        }
    }
```

"Error  3   'string' does not contain a definition for 'IMPORT_TRACKER' and no extension method 'IMPORT_TRACKER' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"

Comment: Well, no it doesn't.  Have you done any research?  [Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqlconnection)'s an example

Comment: There are a [few ways](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/15466/162). `SqlConnection.Query` isn't one of them See [ADO.NET Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021(v=vs.110).aspx) as a start

Comment: Side note: The connection string shouldn't be hard-coded and db access really, really shouldn't be in your view..

Answer (score 2):

It is very bad practise to do it like this. A View is only for displaying information. If you want to query the database, do it in the controller and pass the result to the view as model.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = // do your query here
        return View(result);
    }
}
```

The view could look like the following:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div>@item</div>
}
```

Comment: While I do agree, this doesn't answer the question.